# how to change flask default http method from GET to POST

Tags: python, flask

currently flask use **GET** as default HTTP method, is there any flexible way to change this default method to **POST** for all app.route?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing GET to POST in Python (Flask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095630/changing-get-to-post-in-python-flask)

Comment: thanks for the kindly info;
I wanna to change the default to POST for all the api.route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to do this would be to run your own version of Flask that changes this code to default to a POST

```
# if the methods are not given and the view_func object knows its
# methods we can use that instead.  If neither exists, we go with
# a tuple of only ``GET`` as default.
if methods is None:
    methods = getattr(view_func, 'methods', None) or ('GET',)
```

becomes...

```
# if the methods are not given and the view_func object knows its
# methods we can use that instead.  If neither exists, we go with
# a tuple of only ``GET`` as default.
if methods is None:
    methods = getattr(view_func, 'methods', None) or ('POST',)
```

[Code: Lines 1184-1188](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py)

Though at this point it's probably just simpler to add a method declaration of POST to each route definition.

Comment: thanks for the kindly response, this is not so flexible as everyone need to change the code locally

Comment: @dennyx or you create it once and publish it as a local library for use by your developers. I don't think there is going to be an easier option. Why do you want to change the default behaviour? What's wrong with adding `methods=['POST']` to each `@app.route` annotation?

Comment: thanks for the kindly info;I will publish a local library for usage;
Change this default behavior due to system designed just to support POST request